# Import data from locked websites

Tags: r

I have written code that downloads and reads in multiple web files from a web address, but it only works when I manually click and open each file first. I think this is because the website is locked and when I manually click on the relevant webpage, the code is then able to read in the file without being locked out.

My code is:

```
VAR=c('tas', 'tasmin', 'tasmax', 'pr')
RCP=c('rcp26', 'rcp45', 'rcp60', 'rcp85')
SEQ=sprintf('%0.3d', 0:20)

for(i in VAR){
  for(j in RCP){
    for(k in SEQ){

FILES=read.table(paste0("https://climexp.knmi.nl/data/icmip5_", 
i, "_Amon_mod_", j, "_5-7.5E_50-52.5N_n_su_", k, ".dat"))

colnames(FILES)=c("YEAR", "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", 
"JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC")
write.table(FILES, file=paste0("C:/.../", i, "-", j, "-", k, ".txt"), sep="\t")
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a link to one of the many files this imports:

https://climexp.knmi.nl/data/icmip5_tasmin_Amon_mod_rcp45_5-7.5E_50-52.5N_n_su_000.dat

This opens for me since I have gone to it manually on the site, but probably doesn't open correctly if one of you click on it. This is the problem. I need to amend my code to recognise that these websites are locked/password protected and I need to somehow write some code to first unlock the website, and then download it as I have done above.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that the data is returned after for instance JavaScript delivered it to the front? If so, you need a scrapper which will be able to "visit" the page on its own and returns the data. PhantomJS comes to mind. But before you go any further, check site policy if data scraping is allowed.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik unfortunately (for the OP), what's happening is that the site is generating the data files dynamically after selections are made in the forms. I'm also assuming they're cached for some period of time. I think the only way this is going to work is if the forms are instrumented via `rvest` or `RSelenium`.

Comment: Of note: that `.dat` file was available to me as it has most likely not been un-cached yet.

Answer (score 0):

Without the (for lack of a better term for this) "click path" you took to get to the data the best I can do for you is to show you how to figure out where you need to explore further.

With "developer tools" open in Chrome, I went to to https://climexp.knmi.nl/ which redirected me to https://climexp.knmi.nl/selectfield_cmip5.cgi?id=someone@somewhere and selected "Monthly CMIP5 scenario runs". On there, I chose "1" under "tas" in the "CMIP5 mean" row and clicked "Select field". That brought up another page and I entered your lat/lon into the "Get grid points, average area or generate subset" table boxes and clicked "Make time series". That brought up a resultant page of charts and links to download data.

I had "developer tools" up since I was inspecting what was being passed to each subsequent URL since no parameters were being put on the browser location bar (i.e. they weren't `GET` requests). Thankfully, there are no "sessions" or cookies associated with these requests and the process seems to be repeatable (i tried the "trick" below for "tasmin" and "tasmax" as well and they both worked).

I used "copy as curl" in "developer tools" on the ".cgi" link and used the `curlconverter` package to transform that into an `httr` verb call:

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)

res <- POST(url = "https://climexp.knmi.nl/get_index.cgi", 
            body = list(email = "someone@somewhere", 
                        field = "cmip5_tas_Amon_modmean_rcp26", 
                        maskmetadata = "", 
                        lat1 = "50", 
                        lat2 = "52.5", 
                        lon1 = "5", 
                        lon2 = "7.5", 
                        intertype = "nearest", 
                        gridpoints = "false",
                        masktype = "all", 
                        standardunits = ""), 
            encode = "form")
```

That retrieves the whole page (the one with charts and links to data). We can read that page:

```
pg <- content(res)
```

And then find all the links to data on it:

```
html_nodes(pg, "a") %>% 
  html_attr("href") %>% 
  grep("^data", ., value=TRUE)

## [1] "data/icmip5_tasmax_Amon_modmean_rcp26_5-7.5E_50-52.5N_n_+++.eps.gz"    
## [2] "data/icmip5_tasmax_Amon_modmean_rcp26_5-7.5E_50-52.5N_n_+++__yr.eps.gz"
## [3] "data/icmip5_tasmax_Amon_modmean_rcp26_5-7.5E_50-52.5N_n_+++__yr.txt"   
## [4] "data/icmip5_tasmax_Amon_modmean_rcp26_5-7.5E_50-52.5N_n_+++_a.eps.gz"  
## [5] "data/icmip5_tasmax_Amon_modmean_rcp26_5-7.5E_50-52.5N_n_+++_a.txt"
```

Now, none of those are `.dat` files, but that's prbly due to me not selecting the same options as you.

This should get you on your way, though.